# Input parameter without name in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I print input parameter without name?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_inpt_int 
@ int 
AS 
    select 1; 
GO
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why on earth you want to do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use that variable:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_inpt_int 
@ int 
AS 
    select @;
```

But this is a terrible idea.

Comment: Really.. Doesn't even look like it will compile.. but it works... Just like this `DECLARE @ int SELECT @;`

Comment: @Prdp yeah, it looks like it would throw a syntax error, and I saw a comment saying that this wasn't possible; that's the main reason I answered this question

Comment: @Lamak, it's really works, but what the purpose of declaration without name?

Comment: @IspirerSQLWaysMigrations it has a name: `@`, that's the name of that variable, you won't be able to declare another variable with that particular name. To me, it serves the purpose of confusing people

Comment: @Lamak Actually I think the name is not `@` and the name is .. nothing, an empty string. Using `@` is mandatory when declaring variables so parameters, so I'm guessing the parameter / variable name is optional.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu yeah, I know. I'm just trying to explain this in the clearest way for op

Comment: @Lamak Well I'll be dipped... I don't see the value, but it is truly bizarre.

Comment: This works too `DECLARE @ INT=5;SELECT @;`, funny! Well, it's not ununsual to handle an empty string like any other string, but in this case it's really weird. One reason I love SO is that you find such things!

Comment: @Shnugo Haha, I tested the exact same code after posting my comment a few hour earlier. I'm curious if there is a statistical probability which favors `5` being selected as a test value for SQL code. I find I use it quite often as a test value.